# Почему count равно 5?

Tags: javascript

Почему count равно 5?
Когда card === 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 к count надо прибавить +1
Когда card === 7, 8 , 9  к count = 0
Когда card === 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'  -  count - 1

Как правильно решить задачу?

```js
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  if (card === 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6) {
    count++;
  } else if (card === 10 || "J" || "Q" || "K" || "A") {
    count--;
  }

}
cc(2);
cc(3);
cc(7);
cc('K');
cc('A');
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы неправильно сделали сравнение. Дело в том, что ваше выражение эквивалентно `if (card === 2 || true || true || true  || true )` что эквивалентно `if(true)`. Так как `3`,`4`,`5`,`6` при логических операциях это `true`.

То есть у вас всегда срабатывал первый блок `if`.

Правильная версия кода:

```js
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  if (card === 2 || card === 3 || card === 4 || card === 5 || card === 6) {
    count++;
  } else if (card === 10 || card === "J" || card === "Q" || card === "K" || card === "A") {
    count--;
  }

}
cc(2);
cc(3);
cc(7);
cc('K');
cc('A');
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Не эквивалентно.Эквивалент: `if (card === 2 || true)`, а так да...

Comment: @MedvedevDev Точно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что все что не 0 - это true. Условия нужно записывать полностью

```js
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  if (
    card === 2 ||
    card === 3 ||
    card === 4 ||
    card === 5 ||
    card === 6
  ) {
    count++;
  } else if (
    card === 10 ||
    card === "J" ||
    card === "Q" ||
    card === "K" ||
    card === "A"
  ) {
    count--;
  }

}
cc(2);
cc(3);
cc(7);
cc('K');
cc('A');
console.log(count);
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

`card === 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6` - это работать у вас не будет, так как если в `card === 2` вы получите `false`, то потом при любых раскладах `false || 3` будет выдавать `true`, так как `!!3 === true`

```js
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  if ([2, 3, 4, 5, 6].indexOf(card) >= 0){
    count ++;
  } else if([10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"].indexOf(card) >= 0){
    count --;
  }

}
cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

тоже самое, просто наглядный вариант

```js
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  switch (card){
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
    case 10:  
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      count--;
      break;
  }
}

cc(2);
cc(3);
cc(7);
cc('K');
cc('A');
console.log(count);
```